# Does system app have permission to access /system directory?

Tags: android, android-source

I have an application **signed** with the platform keys and want to access the file e.g **/system/myfile.txt**. Does a system app have permissions to **read** and **write** in **/system/** directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No app or service should be able to **write** to `/system` as it is read-only.

You can check SELinux policies with the `sepolicy-check` tool.

```sh
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch
m sepolicy-check

# Check whether system_app can read system_file.
sepolicy-check -s system_app -t system_file -c file -p read -P $OUT/root/sepolicy; echo $?

# Check whether system_app can write system_file.
sepolicy-check -s system_app -t system_file -c file -p write -P $OUT/root/sepolicy; echo $?
```

The `read` check prints a `Match found!` message and returns `1`. The `write` check only returns `0`, indicating that the allow rule was not found. Since SELinux will only allow what is explicitly allowed in a rule, writing to `/system` is forbidden for system apps.

Comment: I have already checked by accessing the /system directory using a system app, but this is better way to check, thanks